# How to animate the image in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need if he touchBegan on the image size should be increased if he moved the also same but if
in touchesended it needs to be become original size how to do this .can any one share the code to do this ..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Let's guess that your image is implemented as UIImageView, If so, you can use simple transformation.

yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale.x, scale.y);

scale (1.0 - original size)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you subclassed UIImageView - if you did not, you should do it now.
Also, make sure the set the image's .userInteractionEnabled to YES!

Interface:

```
@interface YourImageView : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint originalCenter;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint touchLocation;
@end
```

Implamentation:

```
@implementation YourImageView
@synthesize originalCenter;
@synthesize touchLocation;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    self.originalCenter = self.center;
    self.touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint touch = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    CGFloat xDifference = (touch.x - self.touchLocation.x);
    CGFloat yDifference = (touch.y - self.touchLocation.y);

    CGPoint newCenter = self.originalCenter;
    newCenter.x += xDifference;
    newCenter.y += yDifference;
    self.center = newCenter;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    self.originalCenter = CGPointZero;
    self.touchLocation = CGPointZero;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

    self.originalCenter = CGPointZero;
    self.touchLocation = CGPointZero;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
}
@end
```

You could, if course, warp the self.transform = sth into an animation to make it look better. ;)

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use block-based animations in this case (like Dancreek proposed), because the user would not be able to move the image while this animation is running!

Comment: Block animations will still work just fine but you will have to set UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the frame size of the imageview and scale the image displayed in it (by using scaleimage to fit) in the touchesBegan Method. U can set the frame to orginal size in the touchesEnded method. In this way u can achieve the animation effect u desired.Hope this helps.

Comment: Using UIView's transform property is IMHO way better in this case. In your solution, you would have to store the original frame, while this is not required when using transform. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your touchesBegan

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
}];
```

Place this code in your touchesEnded

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
}];
```

Comment: The code for touchesCancelled should be the same as for touchesEnded. Also, block-based animations don't work well for me in this case. The user is not able to move the view while the animation is running.

Comment: Then use the non-block methods or set the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option.